# How can I trigger recompose when I modify a property of a state which contains a nested array in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

So I have a state which looks like so:

```kotlin
data class CommentViewState (
    var post: Post? = null,
    var post_url: String? = null) {}
```

The `Post` class contains a variable called `CommentChain?` which contains `var tree: MutableList<CommentNode> = mutableListOf<CommentNode>()`. `CommentNode` is structured like so:

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class CommentNode (
    var children: MutableList<CommentNode>? = ArrayList(),
    var collapsed: Boolean = false,
    @SerialName("user") var user: User? = null,
    @SerialName("content") var content: String? = null) {}
```

When I need values from a `Post`, I collect them like so:

`val post_real = view_model.state.collectAsState().value.post`

This is used to represent a tree of comments in memory. When the variable `collapsed` is changed, I would like to trigger recomposition, in order to collapse the comment. How would I go about getting that value change to trigger recomposition?

I've tried changing the value of the property like so: `node.collapsed = true`, but that hasn't made a difference. My expectation is for recomposition to trigger so I can collapse the comment.